# VBA code to put borders around merged cell ranges in dynamic sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am building a dynamic price sheet to send to customers.  I have it set up to hide/show different products and then merge the "Product Family" cells to make it easier to read.  Everything works except trying to dynamically select the entire row to create a thick border around each "product family".  These will change and based on other selections so i can't just specify ranges (like a macro record would show).

Using a For Each loop, i can get the sheet to seemingly make the right selections, however, i cannot get a .BorderAround the whole box, it puts thick lines on the interior rows as well.

[Sample Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuGJa.png)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'find last row before merge
Dim lastrow As Long
  lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

'Merge Cells
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim rng As Range
MergeCells1:
For Each rng In Sheet1.Range("B2:E20")
  If rng.Value = rng.Offset(1, 0).Value And rng.Value <> "" Then
    Range(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
    Range(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Range(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    GoTo MergeCells1
  End If
Next

'Borders
With Sheet1.Range("B1:E" & lastrow)
  .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous 'all gridlines
  .BorderAround Weight:=xlThick 'thick border around whole table
End With

'*****Here's the Problem!!!******
'Borders around each Year set.
'Trying to put a border around this selection:
Dim yr As Range
For Each yr In Sheet1.Range("B2:B" & lastrow)
  With Sheet1
    .Range(.Cells(yr.Row, "B"), .Cells(yr.Row, "E")).Select
  End With
Next

'If i replace .Select with .BorderAround it puts a borderaround each line.
For Each yr In Sheet1.Range("B2:B" & lastrow)
  With Sheet1
    .Range(.Cells(yr.Row, "B"), .Cells(yr.Row, "E")).BorderAround Weight:=xlThick
  End With
Next

End Sub
```

Data starts in column B.  Column A is used to mark which lines are included in the full code.

Running the code will highlight the right selection, but it will thick underline every row.  Looking for thick border around each "Year block"

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the output you were looking for?

[image]

Rather than using `.BorderAround`, I used `.Borders(xlEdgeTop)` to get the same effect, as you already have a boarder all around your data.
This code looks to see where the Year column is merged, and each time it is a new year, adds an upper boarder.
I know this isn't exactly what you were looking for, but does it get the job done? :)

```
Sub TESTING()
'Testing code for the following question:
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58323035/vba-code-to-put-borders-around-merged-cell-ranges-in-dynamic-sheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("TEST_SHEET")
lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Merge Cells:
MergeCells1:
For Each rng In ws.Range("B2:E20")
    If rng.Value = rng.Offset(1, 0).Value And rng.Value <> "" Then
        Range(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
        Range(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Range(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        GoTo MergeCells1
    End If
Next

With ws.Range("B1:E" & lastrow)
    .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .BorderAround Weight:=xlThick
End With

For Each yr In ws.Range("B2:B" & lastrow)
    If yr.Value <> "" Then
        With ws.Range(yr, yr.Offset(0, 3)).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThick
        End With
    End If
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: That's perfect!  Thank you!  I thought I would need to do something with MergeArea or something.

Comment: @RiverChawk happy to help :)